# WebStorm : Latest package version not found

Tags: npm, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, webstorm, yarnpkg

Using WebStorm for the project and have to rely on the VSCode for finding the latest package version number (I know, there are npm and yarn commands)

So what's the issue that, VSCode is able to show the latest package number, while WebStorm stuck on `loading...` and after <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd>, shows `latest not found`.

Images attached for the reference:

[image: WebStorm]

[image: VSCode]

Comment: please share your idea.log (**Help > Show Log in ...**)

Comment: @lena here's log shorturl.at/cdtH8

Comment: the log shows that the packages were not found in NPM registry (http://registry.npmjs.org); are `@gyg/*` packages private?

Comment: Yes... They are hosted in aws codeartifcts